# SQL problems, JOINS

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

Im having some problem with my SQL code. My assignment is to present some information about teachers(Lärare.personnummer) who don't have teach the course "Java2"(Kurstilfälle.kurs). The code is right but my problem is that there is one teacher who don't have teach any course(kurs). So the information about her is not in the result. I want to get this last persons information in my result.

My code--> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pu6uj.jpg

Database--> https://ilearn2.dsv.su.se/mod/resource/view.php?id=21941

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person.personnummer, Person.namn, tjänsterum, telefon
FROM Kurstillfälle,
     Person,
     Lärare
WHERE Person.personnummer = Lärare.personnummer
  AND Kurstillfälle.lärare = Person.personnummer
  AND Lärare.personnummer NOT IN (SELECT Kurstillfälle.lärare
                                  FROM Kurstillfälle WHERE kurs = 'Java2')
```

Maybe someone can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Whats your question?, also put your code in your question and put in your sample data and an expected output

Comment: what tables are tjänsterum & telefon from?

Comment: Please post code as text and not an image so that we can easily copy & edit it for answers. Show us the database model and your query that does not work

Comment: Tjänsterum are from Lärare and telefon is from Person.

Comment: Rename table person as personer, since it holds info about several persons. Also, we are not authorized to see your images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With new style `JOIN`, return a teacher who `NOT EXISTS` as teacher for Java2:

```
SELECT p.personnummer, p.namn, tjänsterum, telefon
FROM Person p
  INNER JOIN Lärare l ON p.personnummer = l.personnummer
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Kurstillfälle
                  WHERE kurs = 'Java2'
                    AND lärare = p.personnummer)
```

**Edit:** I don't know Access syntax, but try `INNER JOIN` instead of just `JOIN`!

Comment: Thanks, but i get syntax error in FROM-instruction.

Comment: im guessing this is part of a larger block of code with the error above?

Answer (score 0):

Using Joins this should get what you want

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.personnummer, p.namn, tjänsterum, telefon
FROM Kurstillfälle k
INNER JOIN Person p ON k.larare = p.personnummer
INNER JOIN Lärare l ON p.personnummer = l.personnummer
WHERE k.kurs !='Java2'
```